# Message.show() on another computer desktop?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-2.0, messagebox

There are two computers established communication via a hub.

If MyAPP.exe exist on Computer A, Assume I want to notify a message window (Pop-up window) on Computer B if MyAPP.exe error occurred. Could I show alert message with Message.Show() on computer B desktop? I remote computer A with 'Remote Desktop Connection' currently. That's why I want the feature.

Appreciated for your reply and comment.

*WindowsXP and C#2.0 used.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the external [`msg`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186480) program or [`net send`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true). The former is part of the Terminal Server suite; the second is built in Windows XP, but was removed in later versions of Windows.

```
msg username /server:computerA "There was an error!"
```

You can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to run an external program.

Comment: The msg command only works if you are connected to a terminal server. I have just tried using msg to send a message from one computer to another and it doesn't work.